# Get focused window title and use it in if statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, window

I found this code around the net but I don't know how to use it. I just want to build a code that will execute if a desired window is active.

This is for API as i read about my research,

```
<DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetActiveWindow", SetLastError:=True,
CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True,
CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>

Public Shared Function GetActiveWindowHandle() As System.IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetWindowText", SetLastError:=True,
CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True,
CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>

Public Shared Function GetActiveWindowText(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

He used this to get the text,

```
Dim caption As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
Dim hWnd As IntPtr = GetActiveWindowHandle()
GetActiveWindowText(hWnd, caption, caption.Capacity)
MsgBox(caption.ToString)
```

I put that code in the `form_load()` but it doesn't display anything. Like nothing happens. Where should I put it or how to make it work. I want to get the window title and put it in an `If` statement. I also found some programmers that used this code:

```
Dim hWnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
```

I just want to determine the window on focus, get the text and put it in an `If` statement. Can you please simplify this code more. What is the difference of a FOCUS window and ACTIVE window? i guess ACTIVE are the open windows but FOCUS is the only one that the user is using. I want to know the title of the FOCUS one.

For example,

```
If "title of the window on focus" = "notepad" Then
   MsgBox("notepad")
Else
   MsgBox("not notepad")
End If
```

And where there is 2 windows open, if the notepad is focused it will display the notepad on message box and when the user change its focus to the other window the message box will automatically display the not notepad message.

Comment: GetActiveWindow only ever runs the active window that's owned by your application.  Which will be none in the Load event, you don't have an active window yet.  Clearly you want GetForegroundWindow() here.

Comment: how can i use the GetForegroundWindow()?? do i need to import another namespace or not? which part of the code should i put it?

Comment: You define it the same way as you did GetActiveWindow and GetWindowText.

Comment: [this url](http://vbtab.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-get-title-of-currently-active-window-in-vb-net.html) might be what you are looking for